# Difference between Unlocked vs Second Generation Managed Package

Tags: unlocked-package, 2gp, 2gp-ama

Bear with me, I'm not sure I fully understand what's given in the documentation.
I understand the difference between [1GP vs 2GP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_comparison.htm).

From what I read Unlocked Packages are different than Second-Generation Packages, What I don't understand is the actual differences between them.

Comment: My understanding is that unlocked packages *are* second generation packages. However, they cannot be posted on the AppExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can list down these:-

1. Second-generation managed packaging (2GP) is intended for AppExchange apps where as unlocked packages are especially suited for internal business apps. If you’re a customer or system integrator and you don’t plan to distribute a package to multiple customers, unlocked packaging is the preferred tool.
2. In order to use unlocked pacakge, you must enable second-generation packaging in your Dev Hub org, so it mean Unlocked Package is a 2-nd generation package
3. Metadata elements are not locked and can be changed by system admins in unlocked package where as Second Generation Managed Package is managed

Comment: To your 3rd point - so it's basically like unmanaged code? the only difference is we package using CLI. @sanket

Comment: the basic difference between unlocked and managed package is Unlocked Packages are always sourced from local files, while Unmanaged Packages and Managed Packages always source from an org. Read here:- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293491/unlocked-packages-vs-unmanaged-packages